# Sitecore Commerce 10 installer Commerce Ops Bootstrap

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

My Sitecore commerce installer fails to bootstrap commerce services. I made sure my Sitecore XP installer doesn't get interrupted and the XP is working. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

**Sitecore Commerce installer Log file output:**

Concatenating: https://commerceops.sc.com /commerceops/Bootstrap()
Result: https://commerceops.sc.com/commerceops/Bootstrap()
BootStrapping Commerce Services: https://commerceops.sc.com/commerceops/Bootstrap()
POST https://commerceops.sc.com/commerceops/Bootstrap() with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :
Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

At C:\Sitecore\Sitecore_XC_install\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.6.0.18\My-Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:296 char:5

- ```
  Install-SitecoreConfiguration @deployCommerceParams -Verbose *>&1 ...
  ```
- ```
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:33:13

**Screenshot:**

[image: Sitecore Commerce 10 Installer]

Comment: Make sure your commerce ops https://commerceops.sc.com is running.

Comment: it's not. that's the problem

Comment: Check your IIS, if app pool is not stopped for this site?

Comment: the app pool for the site is running. However, my Commerce Minnions keeps stopping.

Comment: okay, can you try to change your AppPool Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity and then try?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your AppPool Identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity

[image]

Also if this doesn't help then change in `Plugin.SQL.PolicySet-1.0.0.json` `"TrustedConnection": "false",` and bootstrap then try. Do it for all 4 - `Authoring, Shops, Minions, Ops`.